# SQL select clause with a compound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, compound-index

I have two lookup/reference tables (Subscribed and Unsubscribed) in my Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database with the following structure:

```
UserId int
PublicationId int
```

These fields are indexed together as a compound index.

What I want to be able to do is find all of the records that exist in the Unsubscribed table that do not have a matching record in the Subscribed table (matching UserId and PublicationId)

Functionally, I want something like:

```
select PublicationId, UserId
from Unsubscribed
where PublicationId, UserId not in (
   select PublicationId, UserId
   from Subscribed
)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS? Oracle, SQL-Server, MySQL, SQlite, Postgres?

Comment: Which database? Add tag.

Comment: Thank you to everyone that responded to this question.  All of your responses were very useful to me and I will use as a reference in the future.  On this occasion the EXCEPT clause seems to give me everything I need.  Thanks gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT PublicationId, UserId
FROM   Unsubscribed
MINUS
SELECT PublicationId, UserId
FROM   Subscribed
```

Comment: If SQL product is not Oracle then replace `MINUS` with `EXCEPT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `left join` to find the non matching publications and users.

```
SELECT U.[PublicationId], U.[UserId]
FROM [Unsubscribed] AS U
    LEFT JOIN [Subscribed] AS S ON S.[PublicationId] = U.[PublicationId]
        AND S.[UserId] = U.[UserId]
WHERE S.[PublicationId] IS NULL
    AND S.[UserId] IS NULL
```

Or if you are using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 / 2008 then you can use the `Except` keyword (use the `Intersect` keyword for the opposite).

```
SELECT [PublicationId], [UserId]
FROM [Unsubscribed] 

EXCEPT

SELECT [PublicationId], [UserId]
FROM [Subscribed]
```

Comment: The `[]` are used in SQL-Server only.

Comment: Ahh yes, apologies I am a Microsoft guy, don't judge me too harshly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always convert `IN` to `EXISTS`. In your case, this would look like this:

```
select PublicationId, UserId
from Unsubscribed
where
   not exists (
      select *
      from Subscribed
      where Subscribed.PublicationId = Unsubscribed.PublicationId
         and Subscribed.UserId = Unsubscribed.UserId
   )
```

Incidentally, if you are using Oracle, you can actually implement your original intent directly (just add a couple of parenthesis):

```
select PublicationId, UserId
from Unsubscribed
where (PublicationId, UserId) not in (
   select PublicationId, UserId
   from Subscribed
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [LEFT JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) to achieve this;

```
SELECT U.*, S.PublicationId
FROM Unsubscribed U
LEFT JOIN Subscribed S ON U.PublicationId = S.PublicationId AND U.UserId = S.UserId
WHERE S.PublicationId IS NULL
```

If you are new to join's, [Jeff Atwood's Visual Explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is a good place to start.

Effectively, what the query is doing is bringing back all of the rows in ubsubscribed that have a matching row in Subscribed, and all of the rows in Unsubscribed that have no matching rows in subscribed - the rows in subscribed are represented with NULL's for these.